# NHibernate Envers - Use Guid as Id instead of Int

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

All the examples I have seen for `NHibernate.Envers` use an integer as the object id's. I would like to use `Guid`'s instead. Is this possible?

```
[Audited]
public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual String FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual String LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual Address.Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

I am asking because I am seeing an exception when trying to save the `REV` data:

```
[Sql String]: INSERT INTO REVINFO (REVTSTMP) VALUES (?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'REV', table 'Auditing.dbo.REVINFO'; 
  column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

My revision data object has an Id of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your entites can have pretty much any id type (that NHibernate Core supports). The revision entity must have a number though.

About your exception... Most probably there's something wrong with your revision entity and/or its mapping. Read the docs here, http://envers.bitbucket.org/#revisionlog.

Comment: Thanks Roger, I was able to get it working yesterday. So there is no way to make the `REV` on `REVINFO` a `Guid`? I have concerns with using an `int` or even a `bigint` because eventually those will overflow.

Comment: Envers uses this field for a lot of internal queries like "revision id larger than..", "revision id between..", eg when reading relationships.

Comment: ...so no, I don't think it is possible to "solve". In short terms - each revision needs to have som unique value that is "comparable".